# RandomAccessFile getFilePointer output

Tags: java, io, java-io, randomaccessfile

I have a file `a.txt` with contents written using `writeUTF()`,

```
Dog
Cat
Rat
```

Now, while I'm reading back the contents, I'm also printing the pointer position and the pointer position is not correct.

**Code:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
{
    RandomAccessFile ra = new RandomAccessFile("a.txt", "rw");
    System.out.println("Pointer:  " + ra.getFilePointer());
    ra.writeUTF("Dog\n");
    ra.writeUTF("Cat\n");
    ra.writeUTF("Rat");
    ra.seek(0);
    System.out.println(ra.readLine()+ "  " + ra.getFilePointer());
    ra.close();

}
```

**Output:**

```
Pointer: 0
Dog 6
```

**1).** Shouldn't the pointer position be `4`? Because after reading `Dog` it's position is `3` and after reading `\n` it should be `4`. How is it showing `6`?

**2).** Also, when I read whole file, the position it shows is `17`. But there are only `9` characters, `2` newline characters and `1` EOF(should we consider this also?).

**3).** Instead of `Dog\n` if I write `\n` before `Cat` like `Dog` `\nCat` in `writeUTF()`, it outputs different position which is `8` after reading `Dog`.

**Code:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
{
    RandomAccessFile ra = new RandomAccessFile("a.txt", "rw");
    System.out.println("Pointer:  " + ra.getFilePointer());
    ra.writeUTF("Dog");
    ra.writeUTF("\nCat");
    ra.writeUTF("\nRat");
    ra.seek(0);
    System.out.println(ra.readLine()+ "  " + ra.getFilePointer());
    ra.close();

}
```

**Output:**

```
Pointer: 0
Dog 8
```

Answer (score 0):

getFilePointer shows the position in bytes.  "modified UTF-8" uses 1,2, or 3 bytes to create a character.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInput.html#modified-utf-8

Take note of how the writeUTF method works on the RandomAccessFile object as well:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#writeUTF(java.lang.String)